# Selecting specific file from $_FILES multiple upload php

Tags: php, angularjs, file, angular-file-upload

I try to use the nervgh/angular-file-upload with php/mysql server side script like this:

upload.php

```
if ( !empty( $_FILES['file']) ) {
  $tempPath = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
  $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
  $photo = 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ][0];
  $photo2 = 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ][1];
}
```

I have been editing the original angular-file-upload script like this:

```
alias: 'file[]',
```

It seems to be working but only the first image ($photo) will be uploaded and I don't understand for what reason.

$photo2 will generate an empty array although I load more than one picture.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean that when you select several images and try to upload them, only first is being uploaded?